# Homology groups of orientable surface of genus 2 with some circles identified.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

This question is from Hatcher section 2.1. [image]

I was able to do part (a) fairly easily using the LES of pairs and computing the homology of (X,A) is simple because the space will just be the wedge sum of two tori. But I'm pretty stuck on computing the homology of (X,B). My idea was to use simplicial homology to compute the homology of (X,B)  and came up with a fundamental polygon for the space (using a hexagon and attaching a two cell along $aa^{-1}bcb^{-1}c^{-1}$, which I think is correct) but this is a nightmare for computing homology.

> Is there a simple way to compute the homology of (X,B) using techniques of section 2.1?

Comment: Have you tried Mayer–Vietoris

Comment: $X/B$ is the wedge sum of a torus and a circle.

Comment: To see that $X/B$ is homotopy equivalent to a wedge of a torus and a circle, note that B gets crushed to a point. Expand this to a line segment, so you get a torus with line segment attached at both ends. Now contract a path in the torus that connects the line segments' endpoints.

Comment: How do you see that $X/A$ is homotopy equivalent to a wedge of two tori?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $X/B \simeq T\vee S^1$ use Proposition 2.22 and Corollary 2.25. Same applies to $X/A$. Note that $(X,A)$ and $(X,B)$ are good pairs by Hatchers definition.